# HTML & CSS How do I make it so an entire page is visible to everyone without having to zoom out

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've created a portal page for a website and I'm having trouble making it so users don't have to zoom out to 80% to see everything. Here is a link to the website: https://www.xenofactions.com/

And the code for this portal page I will show you here now. I've tried fiddling around with heights and widths etc but I still can't figure it out. I'm new to HTML & CSS any help would be appreciated thank you in the future! I will now put the block of code below belonging to this portal page.

[Google by default is zoomed in at 100% so when one user opened the website they said I think the website is broken? So I want it so everyone can view it without having to zoom out] Picture doesn't let me upload picture on here for some odd reason ----> https://i.stack.imgur.com/02krC.jpg

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow:300,400,500,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.6.0/sweetalert2.min.css">
<link rel="icon" href="">
<title>XenoFactions | Welcome</title>
<style>{literal}
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/6eYoGo2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.portal-content li {
    list-style: none;
}

.portal-content {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.portal-content .logo {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    max-width: 485px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
   /* PUT CSS HERE TO ALTER WEBSITE TO SINGLE COLUMN */
}

.portal-content .logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
    animation-name: pulse_animation;
    animation-duration: 6500ms;
    transform-origin:70% 70%;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
@keyframes pulse_animation {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    10% { transform: scale(1.05); }
    20% { transform: scale(1); }
    30% { transform: scale(1.05); }
    40% { transform: scale(1); }
    50% { transform: scale(1.05); }
    60% { transform: scale(1); }
    70% { transform: scale(1.05); }
    80% { transform: scale(1); }
    100% { transform: scale(1.05); }
}
.portal-content .links > a {
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .10s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .10s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .10s ease-in-out;
}
.portal-content .link-item:hover {
transform:scale(1.05);
}
.portal-content .link-item {
    transform:scale(1.0);
    display: block;
    min-width: 170px;
    margin: 0px 15px;
    transition: all .10s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .10s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .10s ease-in-out;
}
.link-item:Hover .icon {
    bottom:3px;
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}
.link-item .icon {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    bottom:0;
    position: relative;
    height: 348px;
    width: 217px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    transition: all .10s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .10s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .10s ease-in-out;
}

.link-item.home .icon {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/514244374453026816/518073251486760983/forums.png);
    background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/514244374453026816/518073251486760983/forums.png);
}

.link-item.vote .icon {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/514244374453026816/518073137485840389/vote.png);
}

.link-item.store .icon {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/514244374453026816/518073101460832260/store.png);
}
.link-item.bans .icon {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/514244374453026816/518072933537546250/bans.png);
}
.link-item .text {
    font-size: 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #ed9b10 !important;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black, -3px 3px 0px black;
    margin-top: -10px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
div#players > span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-bottom:3px solid #7360FF;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
span#live{
     font-weight: 700;   
    }
div#players > span span {
    color: white !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
.portal-content {
    position: relative;
}
.clouds {
    -webkit-animation: clouds linear 90s infinite;
    animation: clouds linear 90s infinite;
    background-image: url(f.png);
    background-position: 0 100px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 2710px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

@keyframes clouds{
  from   {transform:translateX(-1366px)}
  to {transform:translateX(0)}
}
</style>{/literal}
</head>
<body>
<div class="clouds"></div>
<div class="portal-content">
    <div class="logo">
        <li><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/514244374453026816/514902610390548520/xenonetwork.png"></li>
    </div>
    <div id="players">
        <span class="playerCount"><b><span class="live"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i></span></b> Server IP :
        <span><strong>play.xenofactions.com</strong></span >
        </span>
        
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <a href="http://xenofactions.com/index.php?route=/forum">
            <div class="link-item home">
                <div class="icon"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://xenofactions.com/index.php?route=/vote/">
            <div class="link-item vote">
                <div class="icon"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="http://store.xenofactions.com/">
            <div class="link-item store">
                <div class="icon"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://xenofactions.com/punishments/index.php">
            <div class="link-item bans">
                <div class="icon"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/6.6.0/sweetalert2.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="//mcapi.us/scripts/minecraft.js"></script>
{literal}<script>
    function playerUpdate() {        $.ajax({            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"},            url: "https://mcapi.ca/query/play.xenofactions.com/players",            dataType: "text",            success: function(data) {                var json = $.parseJSON(data);                if(json.status) {                    $(".live").html(json.players.online);                } else {                    $(".playerCount").html("SERVER OFFLINE");                }            }        })    }
    playerUpdate();
    setInterval(playerUpdate, 10000);
</script>{/literal} 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzX0K.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q10B.jpg
```

Comment: Plz, include some more info like images. What do you mean by the `portal page`. And if you mean the home page `https://www.xenofactions.com/` then I can see it properly without zooming out.

Comment: I added in a picture that you can see.

Comment: You have used fixed units like `px`.

Comment: Reduce the margin, padding, width, height etc for smaller viewports.

Comment: This is how it looks to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldrBL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the `<head>` of your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Without this the browsers won't understand very well the scale of your site.

That said, your front page scales well horizontally, but not so well vertically. This is rather normal, as most sites will require you to scroll down to get all content on a page. But you can try to adapt your content to the vertical axis by using percentages and/or `vh` (viewport height) units in your css to indicate the vertical distance between elements, padding, margin, etc.

You could do something like this with your different CSS classes: Replace your fixed pixel values with fluid % values:

```
div#players > span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7360FF;
  padding: 4% 8%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin: 10% 0;
}
```

Just an example, but if you add enough percentages your page will eventually ble completely flexible and adapt better to smaller and larger screens.

Comment: That just adds a scroll bar from what I see. I added it in check the link it looks very clunky now.

Comment: You added it in the css (style tag) but you have to remove it from there and add just the meta line in the regular html, just after the initial <head> tag of the html document. Outside of the style tag. This will scale the site correctly for all users including mobile, but it will add scrollbars if you don't code it correctly to avoid it. Avoiding scrolling on all platforms is next to impossible, you have so many different devices, pixel densities and landscape/portrait mode, etc. So it is not a viable or accessible option.

Comment: I updated my answer to suggest a way for you to make your site more elastic in the vertical direction. Horizontally it's working. Another tip is to avoid loading so many font styles. You probably don't need 10 different font weights, you could probably do with 2 from each font, like 400 and 700 or something like that.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. But I'm still a bit confused. I'm a bit of a newbie, I'm still not sure where to add your line of code above as my <head> is next to <style>

Comment: @LeeMeally He means you should add that code inside your `<head>`.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I added it in but it did nothing to the site. I have <head> above <style> and implemented his code next to it and it did not work.

Comment: @anatolhiman This is how it looks to me https://imgur.com/a/MmKn5lz at 100% zoom googles default

Comment: @LeeMeally .. I think you have problem with height. While you see your site in big display its look perfect but while you see in small screen then its have scroll thats why its look like broken. Right ?
If i am getting right point then plz comment me back.

Comment: @Bhavik See I'm not really sure what the problem is. Do you think it's height?

Comment: @LeeMeally I think so

Comment: I see that you have fixed the meta viewport tag now. Great. It looks perfect on my 1680 px display. https://imgur.com/a/mrRxAf1 . As a newbie you could try to be a bit more methodical and get into the habit of using best practices. That starts by having a complete <head> with all the typiclal meta tags like lang="", charset="", <title>, favicon, etc. Your code looks a bit sloppy and unconvential. Use helpful tools like Emmet in Vscode. Look at what professional web devs do in their code. CSS styles in head is not necessary, stick them in a separate file to get a cleaner html/php file.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to use percentage values for padding and margin. If you appreciate the input, don't hesitate to upvote or select as chosen answer.